# Jasmine, test if Javascript Object Contains another Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, object, jasmine

I'm using jasmine and I want to test if an object is extending properly another object.

Actually I want to achieve something like sinon.calledWithMatch but for synchronous code.

Jasmine's toMatch is for regex.

I'd like to be able to write something like

```
it( 'contains' , function () {
  expect(objectA).to.contain(objectB);
})
```

or

```
it( 'extends' , function () {
  expect(objectA).to.extend(objectB);
})
```

Thing is that it feels too obvious and I'd like to know if there is already a proper way of achieving this test that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question just to explain that I already have a solution but I'm looking for one using the actual framework, in case that is something I'm missing

At the moment I'm doing

```
var containsObject = function ( objectA , objectB) {
                        var _match =  true
                        angular.forEach(objectB , function ( value, key ) {  //any loop will do
                          if (value !== objectA[key]) _match = false;
                        });

                        return _match;
                      };

                      expect( containsObject( newObjectWithMoreGoodies, oldObject ).to.eql(true);
```